# Excel VBA - Finding the beginning and end of coloured rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a code in Excel VBA, to locate the **beginning** (Cell Address) and the **end** (Cell Address) of coloured rows in a table. The table is a timeline(Horizontal axis- Dates, Vertical axis - General Text). The coloured rows all do not start in the first column, but start in different columns. 
Any help?

Comment: Where does your table start? Or do you want to search ALL columns for a color?

Comment: I want to start searching from the 3rd column onwards

Comment: So basically from Column C onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```
Sub findColoredRows()
Dim startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer, o As Integer
Dim ws            As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer
Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long
Dim cellColor As String, noColor As String
Dim cel           As Range

noColor = -4142              ' this is the color index of NO coloring

k = 3

Set ws = ActiveSheet
With ws
    startRow = .Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row
    startCol = .Cells(1, 3).Column
    Do While startRow > 100  ' I assume your table starts before row 100.  So, if there's no data before row 100, check next column
        k = k + 1
        startRow = .Cells(1, k).End(xlDown).Row
        startCol = k
    Loop

    'Now, we have our starting row - get end row.
    endRow = .Cells(startRow, k).End(xlDown).Row

    endCol = .Cells(startRow, startCol).End(xlToRight).Column
    Debug.Print "Start row: " & startRow & ", start column: " & startCol

    ' How many non colored cells is there in our range?
    Dim noColorCells As Integer
    For Each cel In .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
        If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = noColor Then
            noColorCells = noColorCells + 1
        End If
    Next cel
    Debug.Print "There are " & noColorCells & " non colored cells."

    .Cells(startRow - 1, endCol + 2).Value = "Start Date"
    .Cells(startRow - 1, endCol + 3).Value = "End Date"

    'reDim the array to fit the colored cells
    ReDim tDates(1 To noColorCells + 1)
    i = 1                    'index starts at 1, so set this to 1

    For k = startRow To endRow
        For o = startCol To endCol
            If .Cells(k, o).Interior.ColorIndex = noColor And .Cells(k, endCol + 2) = "" Then
                .Cells(k, endCol + 2).Value = .Cells(k, o).Value
            ElseIf .Cells(k, o).Interior.ColorIndex = noColor And .Cells(k, endCol + 2) Then
                i = i + i
                .Cells(k, endCol + 3).Value = .Cells(k, o).Value
            End If
            ' i = i + 1
        Next o

        i = i + 1
    Next k

End With

MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```

This sub will find the addresses of any colored cells.  If you can explain more what you mean by "locate the beginning and the end of coloured rows in a table." I can tweak this.  Can you post an image of a sample table maybe?

Edit: Per discussion below, try this in case there's not always data in the table, but you want the columns of the colored cells:

```
Sub findColoredBGCells()
Dim startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer, i As Integer, k As Integer, startCol As Integer, endCol As Integer
Dim cellColor As String, noColor As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
noColor = -4142

With ws
    'Get the starting row
    startRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    endRow = .Cells(startRow, 1).End(xlDown).Row

    ' Since we know where the names start and end (less ONE for the "Names" part), let's count how many names we have
    Dim noNames As Integer
    noNames = endRow - startRow
    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then ' Get the first used column with data
        startCol = 1
    ElseIf IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
        startCol = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
    End If

    endCol = .Cells(1, startCol).End(xlToRight).Column

    'Now we have our range, let's use it to loop for blank cells, and add those to an array
    Dim coloredCells() As Variant
    ReDim coloredCells(1 To noNames, 2)
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(startRow, startCol), .Cells(endRow, endCol))
    'rng.Select

    'Now, count how many cells are not blank background
    Dim cnt As Integer, celRow As Integer, lastCelRow As Integer
    i = 1

    lastCelRow = 2
    For Each cel In rng
        cel.Select
        celRow = cel.Row
        If cel.Row <> lastCelRow Then 'This is so we can change the first dimension in the array
            k = k + 1
            coloredCells(k, 0) = .Cells(cel.Row, 1).Value
            i = 1
           ' i = i + 1
        End If

        If cel.Interior.ColorIndex <> noColor Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
            If i > 2 Then i = 2 'Since it's only two dimensions we need, only go up to '1'
           ' ReDim Preserve coloredCells(noNames, i) 'resize the array to hold the new column
            coloredCells(k, i) = .Cells(1, cel.Column).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
        lastCelRow = celRow
    Next cel

For k = 1 To UBound(coloredCells)
        Debug.Print coloredCells(k, 0) & " Start Date: " & coloredCells(k, 1) & ", end date: " & coloredCells(k, 2) & "."
        .Cells(2 + k, 2).Value = coloredCells(k, 1)
        .Cells(2 + k, 3).Value = coloredCells(k, 2)
Next k

End With

MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not have enough reputation points as I do not use this much.....so cant post an image...ill explain more clearly

Comment: Is it advisable to provide such a thorough answer to a question which hasn't yet been attempted by the OP? I feel there are a lot of examples of 'super-user' type questions asked in the Excel tag where people without any VBA exposure just want a button that does what they ask, and this decreases the quality of the tag in general.

Comment: @AbhinathKumar - ah.  Is your table MOSTLY colored?  When you say you want the begenning and end rows, do you mean for each column, you want the FIRST row (starting row 1, going down) and the LAST row in that column that are colored?

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - I worked through that VBA before realizing I wasn't sure what he meant.  But I do agree, that is perhaps a premature answer.

Comment: Basically, there is table with horizontal axis(Column Headers) stating dates like a timeline, and the vertical axis stating names of people(Row Headers). The people have done activities on certain dates (e.g from 12/05/15 to 19/05/15)....the cells under these dates will be coloured....I want the code to automatically tell me the start and end date (where the colour starts and ends)

Comment: Thank you very much for the previous answer anyway, but when I run it, it says run-time error 6 overflow..and the line '' endRow = .Cells(startRow, k).End(xlDown).Row'' is highlighted

Comment: @pnuts Agreed completely.

Comment: I have already tried writing the code, but I keep hitting a dead end...im not asking for the whole answer, but just want some ideas on how to do this. @pnuts so not really relevant

Comment: You could just write a script that takes a range (the range being each row), search in that row for a color, note that cell value, then find the next color, note that value.  Now you have your start and end dates.  Also, regarind that Overflow, change the "endRow", "startRow" to `Long` instead of `Integer`.  Can you please post the code you have so far?

Comment: The problem is...sorry for unclear explanation... all the cells between those two dates are coloured, so I cant just locate the next coloured cell....or could I locate the next uncoloured cell?

Comment: Function SumByColor(CellColor As Range, SumRange As Range) 
    Dim myCell As Range 
    Dim iCol As Integer 
    Dim myTotal 
    iCol = CellColor.Interior.ColorIndex 'get the target color
    For Each myCell In SumRange 'look at each cell in the designated range
        If myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iCol Then 'if the cell color matches the target Color
            myTotal = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myCell) + myTotal 'add the value in the cell to the total
        End If 
    Next myCell 
    SumByColor = myTotal 
End Function

Comment: @AbhinathKumar - I have updated the code in my OP.  This now creates two additional columns which stores your dates.  You should be able to take it from here.  Also, for your code, it's better to put it in your original post, as it doesn't format down here and you're limited by character limits.

Comment: Thank you very much @user3578951

Comment: Very sorry, however the same error is occurring, except this line is highlighted 'noColorCells = noColorCells + 1' @user3578951

Comment: How big is your table?  Change the noColorCells to `Long` instead of `Integer` too.

Comment: I fixed the other problem, but it now seems to say ''run-time error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error'' @user3578951

Comment: Cells(startRow - 1, endCol + 2).Value = "Start Date"   this is highlighted

Comment: If you click "Debug" and hover the mouse over "startRow" and "endCol", what pops up? It should be a number.

Comment: Yes when I Debug, "startRow" = 4 and 'EndCol' = 16384 @BruceWayne

Comment: hm - do you actually have data in cell XFD4?  I have a feeling the code is doing something that doesn't correctly get the last column number.  From your starting cell in the table (the top left most cell), if you go right are there any gaps, skips, or empty cells until the end of the table?

Comment: Nope, no data in XFD, a the moment data only goes up to the x column, and the rows that I need to detect start from column D @BruceWayne

Comment: is there any other way I could send you an image of my table, Maybe an e-mail or something as this is very important

Comment: You can upload it to imgur.com and put a link here.

Comment: Is your sheet ALWAYS going to look like that (i.e. headers start in B1, and rows start in A2)?  If so, use this for `endCol`: `endCol = .Cells(1,2).End(xlToRight).Column` . This will start in B1, then go all the way to the right until a gap in the headers, which would typically be the last of your table headers.

Comment: yes it does, the code ran with no problems and it said done, however no data was outputted (i.e the start date and end date), now when I run it a second time it says ''runtime error 6 overflow'', and highlights ' nocolourcells = nocolourcells + 1'' @BruceWayne

Comment: could you try recreating the same table on your computer and try and run the code and locate the problem please, because a new error pops up everytime when I run it?....thanks @BruceWayne

Comment: sorry ...this line is highlighted now, '' For k = startRow To endRow'' @BruceWayne

Comment: What error occurs when it stops there? Hover the mouse over `startRow` and `endRow`. There should be integers that pop up for you showing the values of those two Variables.

Comment: Do you have data in those blank yellow cells? Or is it literally just a blank table with highlighted cells?

Comment: starttrow = 4.....endrow = 1048576, and no the  cells have no data in them @BruceWayne

Comment: If I close excel and restart it..on the first attempt the code runs with no errors but start date and end date are not displayed...However on the second attempt errors occur

Comment: I added some newer code, that should work even without data in your table. I think that's what was giving you grief on the start and endrow for sure.  Let me know how it works.  Also, was it the columns you wanted? I have it currently returning the index (number) of the column.  If you need Letter, let me know.

Comment: Yeah It worked great!!!!....however you are right I wanted it to return the column header (Start Date)  which the colour starts and the column header(End Date), which the colour ends for each row(person name), but you can just do the first row and ill do the rest....thank you so much @BruceWayne

Comment: @AbhinathKumar - so instead of the columns themselves ("A", "B", etc.) you want to know the dates where the color starts and end? So in your [image you linked to](http://imgur.com/qs2rizV), for row 3, you'd want to just output something like "02/01/2015 to 09/01/2015"?

Comment: So, yeah only 2 values(Start Date & end Date) need to be returned, not all columns containing the colour

Comment: @AbhinathKumar - I updated the second code again, now it'll place the start and end date in columns B and C for each person.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!, worked perfectly, I can now apply this to a simulation model, Thanks again for the hard work @BruceWayne

Comment: @AbhinathKumar - Yay! I'm glad we were able to solve the issue.  More than happy to help!